# FTP website in IIS with anonymous authentication requires username and password

Tags: authentication, iis, ftp, authorization, iis-7.5

I have a FTP website in IIS 8 that I want to expose to public (non-authenticated visitors) that is configured using the following settings from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831655.aspx):

- No SSL
- Authentication: Anonymous (Basic authentication is disabled)
- Allow access to: Anonymous Users
- Read permission selected

Whenever I try to connect to the website externally using the ftp://mysite.com address, I am always prompted with a dialog that says:

> Authentication Required - The server ftp://mysite.com:21 requires a username and password

I've tried every credentials (even for the users that have read permissions to folder that the website is pointing to) and still nothing. `Basic Authentication` is disabled for the website.

How can I configure the FTP site in order to allow external read access for any visitor?

PS: it is okay even with a solution that implies `Basic Authentication` in place since I can provide the users with an account on the server for my purposes, but even with `Basic Authentication` enabled and providing the correct credentials, it failed to authenticate.

Regards, 
Ionut

Answer (score 10):

Four things to check:

1. FTP Authentication->Anonymous Authentication->Enable, then edit, User:IUSR Pass:<blank>
2. FTP Authorization Rules->All Anonymous Users->Read
3. FTP User Isolation->Do not isolate. Start in: FTP root directory
4. Add the "IUSR" account to the root directory NTFS Security Permissions with Read, Read and Execute, and List Folder Contents.

Comment: Nope, still asks for password, and doesn't take lUSR as username when logging in either.

Comment: It is IUSR, as in India, Uniform, Sierra, Romeo. Do not use an L for Lima.

Comment: Add the "Everyone" account to the root directory NTFS Security Permissions with Read and Write also work.

Comment: The above mentioned trouble shooting resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem as you. I've solved it by giving NTFS default read permission to "Everyone" on the desired folder.

Comment: That did it.  My chosen physical folder location lacked the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a pretty thorough write up on enabling Public/Anonymous FTP in Windows Server 2008 through 2012R2. I would double check your settings in the FTP Authentication section.

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/ftpserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication

Answer (score 1):

You must add Anonymous Rule access.

Enable & add new rule for Anonymous access: **FTP Authorization Rules > Add Allow Rule > All Anonymous Users**

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I'd used a mapped drive path (T:\ in my case) as the 'Physical path' for my FTP site.

Changing to using the full drive path (D:\etc\etc) fixed it:

[image: IIS Website Edit Site window showing Physical Path starting with D colon rather than using a mapped path]

As I understand it that issue is caused by how Windows marries up permissions between a mapped directory and the actual physical directory it's mapping to.

Answer (score 0):

Changing NTFS permission by adding everyone to the folder with all permission solved the issue for me.