# FTP Server Authentication trouble

Tags: iis, ftp, ftp-server

I am attempting to set up a simple FTP server. After creating the FTP server and setting up required parameters for anonymous authentication I still cannot access the directory.

Upon hitting the ftp server through file explorer, I get this dialog:

[image]

I want anonymous authentication, so I check the box and then it asks for an email address.

[image]

After attempting to input an email address with our domain, I receive the following message:

> Either the server does not allow anonymous logins or the email address was not accepted. (seen at the top of the screenshots)

I have tried:

- Inputting email address with domain on web server.
- Double checking folder permissions on the server - set to Everyone can read the contents.
- Added new rule for Anonymous access and set to Allow All Anonymous Users
- Changed anonymous authentication credentials to User:IUSR Pass:blank
- FTP Authorization Rules->All Anonymous Users->Read
- FTP User Isolation->Do not isolate. Start in: FTP root directory
  -Add the "IUSR" account to the root directory NTFS Security Permissions with Read, Read and Execute, and List Folder Contents.

Basically all the steps mentioned in this stack overflow question ([FTP website in IIS with anonymous authentication requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048072/ftp-website-in-iis-with-anonymous-authentication-requires-username-and-password))

Still having trouble and unable to access the FTP server. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That prompt indicates you were using a rather old client to connect, which probably only supports FTP active mode (use a search engine to learn what is FTP active/passive). That's very likely to fail and an FTP client with passive mode support should be used instead. Besides, study how to configure firewall for FTP, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7

Answer (score 0):

Find the FTP Authorization Rules component:

[image]

Add the following rules to it, check read and write, then restart ftp site and access it through URL.
[image]